# Remove duplicates after UNION in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, union

I have two tables (`T1` and `T2`)

-First, I select `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, and `V4` from `T1` and remove duplicates based on `V1` and `V2` columns using the `row_number()` function.

-Second, I select `V1`, `V2`, `V3`, and `V4` from `T2` and remove duplicates based on `V1` and `V2` columns using the `row_number()` function.

-Third, I used `UNION` to stack these two tables.

```
(WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4,
row_number()over (PARTITION BY V1, V2  ORDER BY V1) rn
FROM T1)
SELECT V1, V2, V3, V4
FROM cte1 WHERE rn=1)
UNION
(WITH cte2 AS(
SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4,
row_number()over (PARTITION BY V1, V2  ORDER BY V1) rn
FROM T2)
SELECT V1, V2, V3, V4
FROM cte2 WHERE rn=1)
```

Now my question is: how can I remove duplicates from the final stacked table above using columns `V1`, `V2`, and `V3`?

NOTE: If there are duplicates in the final stacked table, then I need to remove the records where `V4`=NULL. However, if no duplicates exist in the final stacked table, I still need to keep records where `V4`=NULL.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And what value of `v4` do you want ?

Comment: There is no requirement for V4 here.

Comment: Just remove `V4` from `select` list. It is not used and you need to eliminate duplicates on other columns what `UNION` actually do. This is what @GordonLinoff was about, I think.

Comment: I actually need V4 in the final result.

Comment: If you *actually need V4 in the final result* then go to comment one by Gordon. How do you want to calculate its value? You've already done this for the `T1` and `T2`: *First, I select V1, V2, V3, and V4 from T1 and remove duplicates based on V1 and V2*. Why you cannot do the same?

Comment: Ah- I see. I need to remove the records when V4 = NULL.

Comment: @astentx "Why you cannot do the same?" I need to removed duplicates from the stacked table and this is what I am asking. thanks!

Comment: So apply *where v4 is null* predicate on each table in `UNION` (to remove the rows you'll not use upstream) and do `UNION` on `V1, V2, V3` as I suggested. You can append `null` literal to the final select list for free (if you really need it), no need to select it from unioned data.

Comment: That would be great, but if there is no duplicates in the final staked table, I still need to keep records with V4=NULL. I only need to remove these records when there are duplicates based on V1, V2, V3. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @user9292 You need to decide how to select the value for the column `V4` in the deduplicated dataset. One possible way of duplicate elimination can be `select v1, v2, v3, max(v4) as v4 from cte2 group by v1, v2, v3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same process of removing duplicates as you have used for both tables.
It would look something like this:

```
WITH cteUnion AS
(   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V1,V2,V3 ORDER BY V1) AS rn
    FROM (
        (WITH cte1 AS(
        SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4,
        row_number()over (PARTITION BY V1, V2  ORDER BY V1) rn
        FROM T1)
        SELECT V1, V2, V3, V4
        FROM cte1 WHERE rn=1)
        UNION
        (WITH cte2 AS(
        SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4,
        row_number()over (PARTITION BY V1, V2  ORDER BY V1) rn
        FROM T2)
        SELECT V1, V2, V3, V4
        FROM cte2 WHERE rn=1)
    ) as union
)
SELECT *
FROM cteUnion
WHERE rn = 1
```

or you can use `DISTINCT` if you just want columns V1,V2,V3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT V1,V2,V3
FROM (
    (WITH cte1 AS(
    SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4,
    row_number()over (PARTITION BY V1, V2  ORDER BY V1) rn
    FROM T1)
    SELECT V1, V2, V3, V4
    FROM cte1 WHERE rn=1)
    UNION
    (WITH cte2 AS(
    SELECT v1, v2, v3, v4,
    row_number()over (PARTITION BY V1, V2  ORDER BY V1) rn
    FROM T2)
    SELECT V1, V2, V3, V4
    FROM cte2 WHERE rn=1)
) as union
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution works for me.

Comment: @user9292 that was what I've asked: "Why you cannot do the same?"

Answer (score 0):

UNION is the same as SELECT DISTINCT while UNION ALL is like using SELECT but for both tables.